# Pushing dynamic updates to HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I have a regular line chart using HighCharts - stock charts.

What I'd like to do is just push an update to the chart when the backend is updated.

I can push the data in pretty easily currently, but I don't know how to just make it update with the new record.

There is this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/edge/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/

but it updates every interval - I only want it to update when the data is pushed in (i.e. no interval specified, just by date/time)

Any ideas how I can modify the above example to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement this without polling the server?

Comment: yes - but I just figured it out, I'll post my answer in a bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add items to an array dynamically in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632180/how-to-add-items-to-an-array-dynamically-in-javascript)

Comment: @Elliot Could you post how you solved the problem?

Comment: I can't help but say that this is the longest 'bit' I've ever seen...3 years so far.