# How to add Series dynamically in Scatter type chart using highchart?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have created a scatter chart using the highcharts [Scatter Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/G9q8q/1/).Now I want to add multiple/dynamic series ie. Products and the values for the series name(Product name).Also the data should be fetched from an array.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632180/how-to-add-items-to-an-array-dynamically-in-javascript/10640458#10640458

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you gone through the API? You are looking for [chart.addSeries()](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart.addSeries%28%29)
[jsFiddle to add series on button click](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/members/chart-addseries/)

Comment: Actually I am new to highcharts.Here in your example it adds a series on the click of the button.Can you help me understand how can I use the code to add the series while making the chart.As I mentioned earlier the series to be added will come from an array.

Comment: Give it a try, you can modify the code in the link, and you can save it by clicking the update button on top, and then the new link can be shared here so that we can see what you tried and what problems you facing