# Highcharts with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add items to an array dynamically in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632180/how-to-add-items-to-an-array-dynamically-in-javascript)

I'm adding data dynamically to highchart but it's showing only empty chart after loading

Here is the link that i tried,
http://jsfiddle.net/XjzFH/30/ and 
http://jsfiddle.net/XjzFH/31/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just push data into the series object and expect it to show up
You will need to use the [`Series.addPoint()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint%28%29) method. This method is really recommended only when you want to set single or a subset of points.

```
chart.series[0].addPoint(d1);
```

If you wish to set all points dynamically (like in your case), then you should use the [`Series.setData()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData%28%29) method instead

```
chart.series[0].setData([d1,d2,d3,d3]);
```

[Add points dynamically | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/Ghp68/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i would like add the data one by one because i'm getting the data from db, if i know the data and length then i can add by using chart.series[0].setData([d1,d2,d3,d3]); but i don't know the length of the data until i run the application.

Comment: ok, so you need to use addPoint in your case then