# How to Implement Highcharts dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add items to an array dynamically in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632180/how-to-add-items-to-an-array-dynamically-in-javascript)

After getting data from database i want to pass it to the series: of highchart. Below is the data.

```
series: [

    // { name: '53411',  data:[8151.74,15105.39]},
    // { name: '53473',  data:[18703.18,6692.23]},
    // { name: '500606', data:[-866.78,1311.01]},
    // { name: '500613', data:[27621.01,68468.79]},
    // { name: '500614', data:[73.3,80.47]}

]
```

But I want this to be created dynamically and for that what I've done is also below:

```
var seriesData = '';
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i == data.length - 1) {
        seriesData += "{ name:'" + seriesProviderName[i] + "', data:[" + providerist[i] + "," + providersec[i] + "]}";
    }
    else {
        seriesData += "{ name:'" + seriesProviderName[i] + "', data:[" + providerist[i] + "," + providersec[i] + "]},";
    }
```

And after that I am passing this seriesData to `Series: [seriesData]` but it will not print the chart. because it is a string and it contains double quotes at the start and end and I've seen it in firebug and i don't know how to get rid of this. For example, "seriedData" this is in firebug.

```
  "{ name: '53411', data:  [8151.74,15105.39]},
   { name: '53473', data:  [18703.18,6692.23]},
   { name: '500606', data: [-866.78,1311.01]},
   { name: '500613', data: [27621.01,68468.79]},
   { name: '500614', data: [73.3,80.47]}
  "
```

I want to remove these double quotes.

Comment: You need to create it as objects in an array, not a string.

Comment: @Amir, did your question get answered? If so, please provide credit!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` or `JSON.parse()` or `jQuery.parseJSON()` (that's probably the best option for safety and compatibility, if you're using jQuery) to turn your string object into a JSON object that can then be passed to highcharts.

Or, as in the comments, you can create your object as an array in the first place by doing, e.g. `series[0]['name']=53411;`

EDIT: `stringify()` goes the other direction... brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on how to load highcharts with Ajax:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/